# most elegant way to pass data to rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

i've to pass data from the third viewController to the rootViewController in a navigationController.

I think to do in this way:

A = rootViewController and B = lastViewController
In B i insert a method like this:

```
-(void)load:(A father)f
{
   self.father = f;  // where father is a retain property
}
```

then when i alloc B in A, before push it i will call load method.

Will it work?

Other way to this operation? (also global variables and singleton, i don't want these 2 because i've a lot of data in memory).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a note: Do not retain the parent class in its child class, they will never get deallocated if they both hold a copy of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Some say singletons are evil, but I think they fill a purpose - but in your case I would go with delegation. Thats IMO the best way to handle data between controllers and models.

Answer (score 0):

1. Long and more appropriate way: Protocol and delegation

   - your rootViewController B will have to implement a protocol, then in your lastViewController you will have to declare a delegate of that protocol, then call something like lastViewController.myDelegate = myParent;
   - this is useful if you want to modularize your components, but based on experience, some classes are very specific with its function and creating a protocol just prolongs the process of doing this basic need of transferring data.  In this case, I suggest you use #2.
2. Short Way: What you said

   - ...but I prefer to pass the parent class on the initialization.  I.e. initWithParent: [myParent], but that's just me.  Also DO NOT retain the parent from a child classes.  Only parent class are allowed to retain its child, else you'll have a memory management problem.  Disadvantage of this approach is that if your controllers get complicated, it will be very hard to separate their logic later just in case you need to separate them, like re-using one component in another project.

Comment: My preference would be creating a designated initializer with the ParentViewController as a parameter (`-(id)initWithParentViewController:(id)viewController;`). And indeed, as Apple has written in documentation, usually a child should not retain it's parent.